# How to read a matrix from text file and store it into 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, text, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner at this. I'm trying to read a file and put it into a 2D array. Here is my code. after it outputs the file it displays the garbage in the memory  and the loop never ends unless it hits 50.

```
include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>  
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char arr[50][50];
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Map.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {

        for ( j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            fin.get(arr[i][j]);
        }


    }
    for (int i = 0; arr[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; arr[j]!=NULL; j++)
        {
            cout<< arr[i][j];
        }
    }



}
```

The text file looks like this

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@                                        @@
@@                                        @@ 
@@                                        @@
@@                 ^                      @@ 
@@                                        @@
@@                                        @@
@@                                        @@  
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                          @@
              @@                          @@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                          @@
@@                                        @@
@@  x x                                   @@
@@                                        @@
@@                                  o     @@
@@                                        @@
@@                        o               @@
@@                                        @@ 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Comment: How is the data arranged inside Map.txt?

Comment: Are you trying to read 50 words or 2500 individual characters?

Comment: your code cannot be compiled:
j is not defined

Comment: What's with end conditions of output loops? `arr[j]` in inner loop seems wrong and why you can't write same conditions as in input loops?

Comment: I am trying to read less than 50 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

const int nSize = 50;
//-- initialize array with 0 --
char map[nSize][nSize] = { {0} };

std::ifstream in;
in.open("input.txt");

int i = 0, j = 0;
while (!in.eof()) {
    char next = in.get();
    if (next != '\n')
        map[i][j++] = next;
    else {
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
}

int rowsCount = i + 1;
for (i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
    j = 0;
    while (map[i][j] != 0) 
        std::cout << map[i][j++];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


return 0;
}
```

All lines of text ends with "end line symbol" '\n' or '\r\n'. This can signalize to go to new row of chars in array.
Since array was initialized with 0, we can use it as flag of end of row in output, but better would be calculate size of array while reading it (if all lines have same size).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but make sure the input matrix in *Map.txt* is 50*50 characters for sure, otherwise you may receive undetermined results.
(`include "stdafx.h"` is missing, because I use g++ instead of MS Visual Studio, but you may add this include for precompiled headers, if you created your project the way VS needs it)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const unsigned int HEIGHT = 50;
const unsigned int WIDTH = 50;

int main()
{
    char arr[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Map.txt");
    string line;

    //let's assume here the proper size of input Map
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
      getline(fin, line);
      for(unsigned int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
      {
        arr[i][j] = line[j];
      }
    }

    //let's assume here the proper size of input Map
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            cout << (char)arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Semyon Burov: Ypur solution is much nicer than the one I suggested. The reason why I think **haitham hany** would be satisfied with a simpler, but not so secure solution too to learn more about this problem first. Anyway, nice job!

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to do what I think you are, try this:

```
include "stdafx.h"
include <iostream> 
include <fstream>  
using namespace std;



   void main()
{
    char arr[50][50];
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Map.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {

        for ( int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            fin.get(arr[i][j]);
        }


    }
    for (int i = 0; arr[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; arr[j]!=NULL; j++)
        {
            cout<< arr[i][j];
        }
    }



}
```

the data inside the text file is :

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@                                        @@
@@                                        @@ 
@@                                        @@
@@                 ^                      @@ 
@@                                        @@
@@                                        @@
@@                                        @@  
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                          @@
              @@                          @@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                          @@
@@                                        @@
@@  x x                                   @@
@@                                        @@
@@                                  o     @@
@@                                        @@
@@                        o               @@
@@                                        @@ 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Comment: How does this help in populating a 2D array?